# Is Given annotation compulsory in JBehave story

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, jbehave

For some of our JBehave stories, preconditions are not that obvious and we end up only using @When and @Then in a lot of scenarios without using @Given. Is this considered as good practice or you must have @Given in each scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `SpecFlow` from last four years but never come across any scenarios that I can ignore `@Given` step :) .

You can ignore `@Given` step but it not a good practice. As per my knowledge before testing any scenario we should at least do some pre conditions like opening the application or logging into the application. You can use `@Given` step for those kind of steps.

Scenarios should always imply a specific user role like user stories in Agile. Because each application will contain some specific user roles.

EX: `Given As a sales manager I will login into some application`

In my case I am using `Background` step to open the application(common for all the scenarios).

See my sample scenario below:

```
Feature: BrentScenarios
    Background:
        Given I have Echo application

Scenario Outline: BRT - Create event for Special Collections
Given I have logged in using "<username>" and "<password>"
And I navigated to create event window
```

In minimal case you can use `@Given` step to open your application.